# Trying to create a vector of COORD, causes linking error

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

my code is:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include "field.h"

class output
{
    void putAtLocation(COORD, char chIcon); //currently this outputs to console

    static std::vector<COORD> m_vsOutputBuffer;
public:
    output(void);

    static void addToken(COORD);
    void drawTokens();

    ~output(void);
};
```

and the linker error is:

```
output.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::vector<struct _COORD,class std::allocator<struct _COORD> > output::m_vsOutputBuffer" (?m_vsOutputBuffer@output@@0V?$vector@U_COORD@@V?$allocator@U_COORD@@@std@@@std@@A)
```

this must be the problem line:

```
static std::vector<COORD> m_vsOutputBuffer;
```

I've been at this for hours stuck. <strike>I finally noticed that changing `COORD` to `int` causes the linker error to go away.</strike> I've read that it's(linker errors) are usually caused by dependency issues. <strike>But here it just changing a `TYPE`.</strike> I've also read it can be caused by using a function in a way it wasn't supposed to be. I figure it has to be the way  is handling `COORD`s; or something about `COORD`S is forward declared, or referenced in output.cpp properly.

Edit:
all changing to int did was make compiler errors that caused it never to hit the linker.  now I am back to nothing

and the cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "output.h"
#include <vector>

static std::vector<int> m_vsOutputBuffer;

output::output(void)
{
}
void output::addToken(COORD sCoordinate) //mark a coord in the buffer as needing refreshed
{
    m_vsOutputBuffer.push_back(sCoordinate);
}

void output::drawTokens() //release the outputbuffer the the output window
{
    for (unsigned int iii = 0; iii < m_vsOutputBuffer.size(); iii++)
    {
        putAtLocation(m_vsOutputBuffer[iii], field::checkHit( m_vsOutputBuffer[iii] ) );
    }
}

void output::putAtLocation(COORD sCoordinate, char chIcon) //outputs a single character to the console
{
    DWORD dwNumWritten = 0;
    LPDWORD lpdNumWritten = &dwNumWritten;

    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(
    GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), //***repeatedly getting this handle may end up a bottleneck
    LPCTSTR(&chIcon),
    1,
    sCoordinate,
    lpdNumWritten
    );
}

output::~output(void)
{
}
```

also I found this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/6111/

so I tried moving the static statement to the cpp file and it compiled and ran. but not its not a member variable. So I Need to somehow forward declare the vector.(before the declaration was also creating the static object in the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this line in your `.cpp` file:

```
std::vector<COORD> output::m_vsOutputBuffer;
```

(Note the absence of `static` and the scope `output::`)

This is the actual *definition* of the member variable. What you have in the class (`.h`) is only the *declaration*.

Without this the static variable `output:m_vsOutputBuffer` does not exist and the linker rightfully complains that it can't find it.

Comment: error C2371: 'm_vsOutputBuffer' : redefinition; different basic types

           is the error give if I add that. I think that it is impossible to only declare a vector now after reading some more.

Comment: seems that `COORD` with which your precompiled headers where created and `COORD` with which your .cpp is compiled are different somehow? It's been years that I worked with MSVC so I am a bit rusty... I'd try to disable precompiled headers temporarily and see what happens. Also, AFAIR, it is a good practice to include your headers anyway and not count on stdafx to have them already

Comment: WOW, well I disabled the PCH, and it built, enabled it, still builds....   I really wanna know what this could have been.

Comment: @Zak: I (vaguely) remember that such situations are the downside of using PCH... it helps to do a "clean build" sometimes, i.e. clean the project and rebuild it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Coord is defined in windows.h header... Look into stdafx.h if there is something like 
`#include <windows.h>`. 
Other than that I tried to copy your code add this header and compile it.. went smooth

To edited version:
You probably forgot to change

```
static std::vector<int> m_vsOutputBuffer;
```

back to

```
static std::vector<COORD> m_vsOutputBuffer;
```

But I assume you had it that way before.. Second thing is that you don't have to include the same headers in header and cpp file but this is not causing it.. It is the line in cpp file with

`static std::vector<COORD> m_vsOutputBuffer;`

change it just to:

```
std::vector<COORD> output::m_vsOutputBuffer;
```

You can read on why in this text:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm

Simply said you need do define not just declare.

Comment: yea I do have it included in the `stdafx.h` header. I mean the compiler is recognizing it as a type fine.  Also I just edited my Question, it seems as tho the problem is from making a static vector, which I have done before, the same way... so i don't have a clue.

Comment: well as I said this piece of code is not causing problems, I can link it (using just windows.h and vector headers..) So it's your compiler missing some paths to basic libraries, or you got something wrong whit cpp file.. I'd bet on second one so try post it there..

Comment: yea, I started adding those redundant headers as a last ditch effort for the linker to see something it needed. let me try to read a comprehend the rest of this.